# AutoUpdate with XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm having some problems, can't findout what is problem with my Update system. I'm using XML file for it. What I'm trying is to get application to read xml file for updates(like some news system) and to get updating application if there is new version. I added already on top of project `ReadOnly _reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("C:\launchernews.xml")` Still update system doesnt work, but news system does.

Here is code of it:

```
Public Sub AutoUpdate()
    Dim CurrentVersion As String = My.Application.Info.Version.ToString '--- Change this to Current version, needs changing on every update
    Dim ProgramName As String '--- Change this to Your Progran Name
    Dim GetVer, GetVerLink As String
    Dim GetUpd As Integer

    Using _reader
        While _reader.Read()
            ' Check for start elements.
            If _reader.IsStartElement() Then
                If _reader.Name = "application" Then
                    Dim attribute As String = _reader("name")
                    If attribute IsNot Nothing Then
                        ProgramName = attribute
                    End If
                    ' Text data.
                    If _reader.Name = "version" Then
                        Dim version As String = _reader("name")
                        If version IsNot Nothing Then
                            GetVer = version
                            If _reader.Read() Then
                                GetVerLink = _reader.Value.Trim()
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If GetVer > CurrentVersion Then
                GetUpd = MsgBox(ProgramName & " is an old version." & vbCrLf & "New Update is available" & _
                vbCrLf & "Current version: " & CurrentVersion & vbCrLf & "Version Avalible: " & _
                GetVer & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Update Now?", vbYesNo, "Update")
                If GetUpd = vbYes Then
                    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog

                    sfd.FileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(GetVerLink)
                    If sfd.ShowDialog = True Then
                        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(GetVerLink, sfd.FileName)
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox(ProgramName & " is upto date." & vbCrLf & "Current version: " & CurrentVersion, 0, "Update")
            End If
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Here is XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Launcher>
  <news name="Latest Updates">
 We thank you for your patience throughout this update.
    </news>
  <application name="Launcher">
  <version name="1.0.0.0">
  </version>
  </application>
</Launcher>
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "update system doesnt work".  In what way does it not work.  What are the expected results and what are the actual results?

Comment: Expected results are on form load to show textbox - `MsgBox(ProgramName & " is an old version." & vbCrLf & "New Update is available" & _
                vbCrLf & "Current version: " & CurrentVersion & vbCrLf & "Version Avalible: " & _
                GetVer & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Update Now?", vbYesNo, "Update")` If there is a new update or to show - `MsgBox(ProgramName & " is upto date." & vbCrLf & "Current version: " & CurrentVersion, 0, "Update")` if there is no update at all. But i think problem is that it doesnt read .xml file correct at all.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger and to step through your code?

Comment: Doesnt show anything, application starts, news get loaded thats it.

Comment: Does it call the AutoUpdate method?  If so, what lines in that method get executed?

Comment: I made it on form load:
`Readnews()
AutoUpdate()`

Comment: It doesn't sound like you understand how to use the debugger.  You should do some reading on how to use the debugger.  For instance, look at how to use breakpoints, how to step through code, and how to inspect variable values.